# How to Show different data form a DataSource on DataGridviewComboboxColumn for each rows in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

**Dear Sirs**
I have a datagridview than bind to Table 1 .
so i have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that bind to table  2 .
Suppose  table  2  contains [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t].
The DataGridViewComboBoxColumn must show only [a,b,c,d,e] For the first row and show only [f,g,h,i,j] For the Second row and show only [k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t] the third row.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A combobox in a grid column must contain all the same values for every row. However, you can filter the values so that the combobox appears to have different content.
I answered a similar questions here that demonstrates adding a filter to the datasource of the combobox:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b23d9e8f-a00a-49ba-adf5-52d87c1b2890/parent-child-comboboxes-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols